# when firebase cloud function triggering firestore (onUpdate) typescript error is showing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.archiveChat = functions.firestore
                     .document('chats/{chatId}')
                     .onUpdate( snap => {
                        const data= snap.after.data();
                        const maxLen = 100;
                        const msgLen =  data.messages.length;
                        const charLen = JSON.stringify(data).length;
                        const batch = db.batch()

                        if( charLen >= 10000 || msgLen >= maxLen){
                            const deleteCount = msgLen - maxLen <= 0 ? 1 : msgLen - maxLen 

                          data.messages.splice(0,deleteCount);

                            const ref =  db.collection("chats").doc(snap.after.id)

                          batch.set( ref, data ,{ merge : true });
                             return  batch.commit();
                        } else{
                            return null;
                        }
                        })
```

no-use-before-declare is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> functions@ build /Users/thedkn/Desktop/cmeraApp1/functions
>   tsc

src/index.ts:39:45 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

39                             const msgLen =  data.messages.length;
                                               ~~~~

src/index.ts:46:31 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

46                               data.messages.splice(0,deleteCount);
                                 ~~~~

src/index.ts:50:47 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'DocumentData | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentData'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.

50                               batch.set( ref, data ,{ merge : true });
                                                 ~~~~

Found 3 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/thedkn/.npm/_logs/2019-06-05T00_10_17_788Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
Dhirajs-Air:functions thedkn$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const data= snap.after.data()` can return undefined in the event that there is no "after" snapshot.  Your code needs to check for this, as long as you have strict mode enabled for your TypeScript compiler.

```
const data= snap.after.data()
if (data) {
    // now it's safe to use data because it's certain to be defined
}
```